# How do I install extra kernel modules in a KVM kernel?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu VM built from the `focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img` image.  The problem is that I am trying to install a package that requires kernel modules not included.   Specifically, I need to be able to:

```
modprobe dm_snapshot dm_mirror dm_thin_pool
```

Looking through the repositories, these modules are included in, for example,
the package, `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic` but the version of kernel I got was

```
# uname -a
Linux gl1 5.4.0-1062-kvm #65-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 21:51:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There doesn't seem to be a "modules-extra" package that corresponds to this version.  How do I get these modules into my VM?

Comment: Is it an option for you to re-install your VM using the regular Ubuntu server `img` file? It would then use the normal kernel.

Comment: @DougSmythies I was considering that but do those images boot up with cloud-init the way the cloudimg images do?  It looks like I would have to completely rebuild all the installation work I have done so far and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: @DougSmythies it appears that your suggestion is the right one.  There is a a variant that has the generic kernel and the cloud-init configuration: `focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img `